# Add Linux VPS (cloud VPS) to Local Network using VPN or IPSec

Tags: openvpn, site-to-site-vpn, pbx, linux-vserver

I have a Linux (Debian 8) VPS (cloud based VPS, not on Google Cloud platform, but that should not matter) on running a software PBX system.

I want this remote cloud based Linux VPS to appear on my local LAN (local subnet) as if I bought a blank Intel based computer, installed Linux Server (Debian 8) on it, and added it to my local network.

I want the remote Linux VPS (has a public IP from my cloud hosting provider) to appear like it's has a IP address on my local subnet behind my router/firewall (static public IP from my ISP) like the rest of my computers and IP phones that receive their local addressing via DHCP from the my router.

I believe OpenVPN would be appropriate technology to achieve this goal, but I don't see any detailed written down steps to add a remote Linux VPS to a local network using OpenVPN from anyone who has successfully done it before.  I'm a bit surprised.  I thought this is what OpenVPN was for.  Based on what I've seen a OpenVPN bridge may be the best approach to achieve the goal, but again, I don't see any documentation from anyone that has successfully achieved the same or similar goal that I'm after.

Has anyone been able to add their remote Linux VPS to their local subnet using OpenVPN or even IPSec?  Detailed written down steps would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help and time.